# Is it possible to create a mesh between two different objects that has single edge via Animation Nodes?

Tags: animation, vertices, edges, animation-nodes

I'm not really that good at animation nodes, but want to know if it is possible to create a mesh or fill a plane between two edges. I was planning to make a trail using animation nodes, so I have this: https://gyazo.com/cffff87116688f8d92d0e946324243ba
Nodes:
https://gyazo.com/e9ddf6ee903c6d7abb62986ac1f4eace
But I have fill the gaps. So I decided to fill those gaps even though they were separate objects, and the other objects are just created in AN loops. I've tried my best in explaining, tha

Comment: I've tried this different method in creating trails https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/4zn997/different_methods_for_motion_trails_in_animation/ but none of them worked efficiently

Comment: I also tried this objects to hook it to a plane, but animation nodes is not observing hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your vertices are in a typical order, you can use the polygon and edge indices from a grid mesh to construct you mesh as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Blend file:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for this, but where can I find "mesh object input" node. I'm just new at animation nodes :) Thanks for response (BTW i see you everywhere)

Comment: @WorshipLyrics You are using a very old version of Animation Nodes. Try to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: can I have the blend file :) ?

Comment: @WorshipLyrics Added blend file.

Comment: Oh, thanks! but this is not what I've ask. I wanted to connect the vertices that is separate object to each other, the file you've send are one object. Thanks for response tho! I know it's kinda possible. :)

Comment: I'll try to send the trail file i've made

Comment: Loop over your objects, append their vertices locations to a vector list, apply the above node tree. It is fairly easy to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88286/discussion-between-worship-lyrics-and-omar-ahmad).